# Gelfand–Tsetlin patterns of Hermitian matrices and $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ representations

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory

I am wondering about a connection between eigenvalues of Hermitian matrices and Gelfand–Tsetlin bases for irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$  (or $\mathrm{GL}_n$).

Let $M$ be a Hermitian $n\times n$ matrix and write down its eigenvalues in weakly increasing order $\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \cdots \le \lambda_n$. Now remove the last row and column and write the eigenvalues again. Repeating this process yields a pattern like
$$
\begin{matrix}
\lambda_1^{(n)} && \lambda_2^{(n)} && \lambda_3^{(n)} &&\cdots && \lambda_n^{(n)} \\
& \lambda_1^{(n-1)} && \lambda_2^{(n-1)} && \cdots && \lambda_{n-1}^{(n-1)} \\
&& \ddots && \ddots\\
&&& \lambda_1^{(2)} && \lambda_2^{(2)} \\
&&&& \lambda_1^{(1)}.
\end{matrix}
$$
By Cauchy's interlace theorem, this pattern satisfies the inequalities $\lambda_i^{(k)} \le \lambda_i^{(k-1)} \le \lambda_{i+1}^{(k)}$, i.e. each entry is bounded between its two upwards neighbors.

Such patterns are called Gelfand–Tsetlin patterns, as they also arise in representations theory, where they enumerate so called Gelfand–Tsetlin bases of irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, the Lie algebra of all complex $n\times n$ matrices with $[X,Y]=XY-YX$.

The irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ are given by integer partitions $\lambda = (\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \cdots \le \lambda_n)$ and when such a representation $V(\lambda)$ is restricted to $\mathfrak{gl}_{n-1}$  considered as the subalgebra of all matrices with the entries in the last row and column being zero, it may again be expressed in terms of irreducible representations. This idea yields the branching rule
$$
V(\lambda)\big|_{\mathfrak{gl}_{n-1}} \ \cong\ \bigoplus_{\mu} V(\mu),
$$
where the direct sum ranges over all integer partitions $\mu = (\mu_1 \le \cdots \le \mu_{n-1})$ satisfying the interlacing condition
$$
\lambda_1 \le \mu_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \mu_2 \le \cdots \le \lambda_{n-1} \le \mu_{n-1} \le \lambda_n.
$$
Applying this branching recursively, one ends up with a direct sum of $\mathfrak{gl}_1$ representations and hence expresses $V(\lambda)$ as a direct sum of $1$-dimensional subspaces, each corresponding to a triangular Gelfand–Tsetlin pattern as above, with all entries integers and the top row being $\lambda$. Picking some non-zero vector in each of the $1$-dim subspaces one obtains a Gelfand–Tsetlin basis of $V(\lambda)$.

Since the exact same patterns appear as spectra of truncated Hermitian matrices and as enumerators for basis vectors of $V(\lambda)$, I am wondering wether there is some connection lurking?

Any references, thoughts or pointers are welcome!

Comment: [+1] interesting. Sorry, no advice: I have worked on Cauchy interlacing theorem but not  on irreducible representations of $\frak{gl}_n$...

Answer (score 1):

The canonical reference for the relationship between representation theory and eigenvalues of Hermitian papers is Klyachko's foundational article *Stables bundles, representation theory and Hermitian operators*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference! However, it seems that Klyachko only treats the relation of components of tensor products $V(\lambda)\otimes V(\mu)$ to possible spectra of sums of Hermitian matrices $A+B$ with spectra $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively. I am looking at components of the restriction $V(\lambda)\big|_{\mathfrak{gl}_n}$ in comparison to possible spectra of projections of Hermitian matrices $A$ with spectrum $\lambda$.

Comment: @Christoph Sure, which is why my answer is worded the way it is. I don't know that the answer to your question is literally included in Klyachko's article (though I wouldn't rule out the possibility that a small variant of his ideas gives exactly what you are looking for).

Comment: @Christoph Also, I don't know you, and I apologize in advance if I sound patronizing, but the usual thing to do in this circumstance is to have a look through the papers citing Klyachko to see if any of them have addressed your question.